# flex column and wrap will let flex-item overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

A simple layout that I want to achieve with **minimal html tags**

Only `<img>` & `<h1>` & `<p>` and no other extra tags

flex + column + wrap

The first column has only one image

The second column contains the title and crossword

The width and height of the parent layer are fixed

The result is that part of the text will overflow

Only add width to `<p>` to prevent

Is there any way to automatically break text without adding width?

HTML

```css
*{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .out{
      width: 600px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      font-family: Verdana;

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    img{
      /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    p{
      line-height: 1.6;
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

```html
<div class="out">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/200/200" alt="">
    <h1>This is Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta iure iusto cupiditate sequi aperiam, nostrum optio ipsam dicta modi officiis eligendi vel. Dignissimos delectus exercitationem nemo. Enim id sed corrupti!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution as per your expecation:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.out {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: Verdana;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
  margin-right: 20px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

p::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/200/200" alt="">
  <h1>This is Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta iure iusto cupiditate sequi aperiam, nostrum optio ipsam dicta modi officiis eligendi vel. Dignissimos delectus exercitationem nemo. Enim id sed corrupti!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```css
* {
  font-family: 'poppins';
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #8f8f8f;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.content h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/150">
  <div class="content">
    <h6>This is title</h6>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
      here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't want to add an extra div if possible

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/musasi69112/pen/mdqypqE

Comment: why are you applying width? and the solution I have provided is the best one

Comment: I know it would be easy to add content div to the layout, just wanted to try it with minimal tags